# Does Bluemix support MBaaS (Mobile Backend as a Service)?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services, mbaas

I am reading about and then trying to use IBM Bluemix. I have seen some confusing statement about MBaaS support on Bluemix. Some sites mention that Bluemix is a PaaS, and some places say it supports MBaaS. I have basic doubts: does IBM support MBaaS? If yes, where can I find the full MBaaS features list for IBM Bluemix? I couldn't find it in IBM site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **Bluemix Mobile** supports a Mobile Backend as a Service.

Here are the current services that we have that support the MBaaS pattern and a bit of information about them (and [here's a quick graphical view](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/bluemix-services/) and some links for how to get started):

**Mobile Client Access**

This service enables you to secure your Mobile Application. You can add Facebook, Google, or custom authentication to your application.

**Push Notifications**

You can add the Push Notifications service to send push notifications to your app on Android and iOS.

**Mobile Analytics (Beta)**

The Mobile Analytics service enables you to gather crash and usage knowlege about customers using your mobile app.

**Cloudant NoSQL DB**

The Cloudant service is the IBM NoSQL database to store your data.

**Object Storage**

The Object Storage service is an unstructured cloud data store where you can store things like images or files.

---

**Mobile Foundation**

The catalog also includes the Mobile Foundation service which you can use to create a test environment before deploying or purchasing the on-premise software. This service is another way for enabling a developer to create a mobile channel.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct: Bluemix is a PaaS. However as you probably know and as you can see [here](http://www.ibm.com/mobilefirst/mobile-backend-as-a-service/mbaas.html):

> Mobile backend as a service (MBaaS) enables you to quickly integrate
>   your mobile apps with data and functions in security-rich, backend,
>   cloud storage. MBaaS is usually delivered through a set of custom
>   software development kits (SDKs) and application programming
>   interfaces (APIs). MBaaS can offer you full data synchronization, user
>   management, push notifications, integration with social networking
>   services, and file-handling.

A PaaS provides SDKs and APIs and for this reason it can support MBaaS. In Bluemix the MBaaS capabilities are provided by the *MobileFirst* platform. It is designed for building and enhancing multiplatform, enterprise-grade apps that can be native or hybrid – for Android, iOS, and Windows. You can get started [here](http://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/bluemix/mobile/).

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at this :
http://www.ibm.com/mobilefirst/mobile-backend-as-a-service/mbaas.html